Plaster crumbling post-flood. Is the wall still wet?
I'm a renter in NYC and had a huge flood in my apartment one month ago. The water tank above my unit leaked and soaked my room. The ceiling plaster fell in 2 places and water was pouring in. It was also streaking down the walls.
Despite my requests, the landlord never brought in pros to deal with this. They just cut 2 small holes in the ceiling to let it dry and called it good. There was tons of visible black mold inside the holes. Finally, after 3 weeks and lots of begging on my end, they ripped out the impacted ceiling and replaced the sheetrock. They also scraped the walls where the paint had rippled and cracked from water damage, then applied plaster to the damaged area.
That was 10 days ago. Today, I went to paint the walls and ceiling with Kilz primer. On two of the walls the plaster immediately bubbled up. On one of them, the plaster started straight up wiping off my wall. (See photos.) Lots of bubbles also appeared on the walls once I primed them. There were other places where the wall rippled significantly when I put primer on it too, like wave pattern. (It's like the original paint isn't attached to the wall, and it's stretchy. So when I used the roller to add primer, I kinda stretched it out. When the primer dried, the wall sucked back in and isn't rippled anymore, but if I push on it with my hands I can move the paint around and move it back into the ripples.)
Why would this happen? My thought is that the walls are still wet...which means there's probably TONS of mold behind them and the landlord needs to rip them out. Is there any other reason why primer would react with the walls this way?
For what it's worth, I used the same primer today on top of plaster in my bedroom ceiling. It's the same plaster, but it only had 4 days to dry instead of 10. There were no issues painting there.



black mold is just mold that eats food that causes it to be black.  toxic black mold requires a lab test.  black mold in general isn't any worse than any other color.  mold grows on trees and is in the dirt so fresh air has mold spores in it too.  mold in your walls probably affects your IAQ less than mold outside on the exterior of your building or on the trees near your building (depending on how your ventilation works.  your priming issue is probably latex on oil - did you buy the multipurpose primer that works with oil?

The primer is Kilz, which the landlord provided. It caused no problems when painted on other areas of paint and plaster today, as described in the post. The only issue was on the walls that were soaked.

kilz is usually pretty good.  drywall is bad for mold since it has a paper backing, plaster is actually pretty resistant to mold.  hard to tell what you have.  sheetrock is drywall.  drywall compound is typically used to mud / tape drywall.  could be the walls are wet.  I've repaired many leaks and as long as the heat is working air dry is typically good enough it takes a while for mold to grow.  slow leaks that have been ongoing for a long time are the more problematic.  water staining and dust can also easily be confused for mold.

The walls are not plaster. Plaster was used to repair the walls and ceiling, which are made of sheetrock/drywall as described in the post. Mold grew on the ceiling sheetrock within 48 hours. It doesn't take long to grow at all.

I can't answer your question, but I can tell you how to answer it.
The tool you need is called a 'moisture meter'. There are pin-type and pinless. The pin type can give more reliable readings but might leave small pin marks. Check in a lot of spots. You want to see readings of 15% or less, ideally around 5-10%. If you see higher readings, yes, things are wet.
Primer can fall off the walls for a bunch of reasons. This will at least let you eliminate moisture as a reason.
